# React component not updating after click

Tags: reactjs

I just created my first React app, https://split-calc.herokuapp.com/

If I fill out the top form first and then click 'Add Person', everything works normal. However, if I click 'Add Person' before filling out the top form, once I fill out the top form, none of the numbers for Person are updated. Why is this happening even though I set each value to be linked to state?

```
function Header() {
    return (
        <header>Split Bill Calculator</header>
    )
}

function AddPerson(props) {
    return (
        <div className='button'>
            <button className='addPerson' onClick={props.onClicked}>Add Person</button>
        </div>
    );
}

function PersonList(props) {
    return (
        <div>
        {props.persons.map((person, index) => (
            <span key={index}>{person}</span>
        ))}
        </div>
    );
};

class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
            this.state = {
                meal_total: 0,
                shared_items: 0,
                tax: 0,
                tip: 0,
                persons: [],
                counter: 1,
            };
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
            this.handleMealChange = this.handleMealChange.bind(this)
            this.handleSharedItemsChange = this.handleSharedItemsChange.bind(this)
            this.handleTaxChange = this.handleTaxChange.bind(this)
            this.handleTipChange = this.handleTipChange.bind(this)

    }

    handleMealChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            meal_total: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    handleSharedItemsChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            shared_items: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    handleTaxChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            tax: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    handleTipChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            tip: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    handleClick = () => {
        let counter = this.state.counter + 1
        let addPerson = this.state.persons.concat(this.renderPerson())
        this.setState({
            persons: addPerson,
            counter: counter,
        });
    }

    renderPerson = () => {
        return (
            <Person
                person_tax = {this.state.tax}
                person_tip = {this.state.tip}
                shared_items = {this.state.shared_items}
                counter = {this.state.counter}
            />
        )
    }

    renderAddPerson = () => {
        return (
            <AddPerson 
                onClicked= {() => this.handleClick()}    
                />
        );
    }

    render() {
        let grand_total = parseFloat(this.state.meal_total) + ((parseFloat(this.state.meal_total)) * (parseFloat(this.state.tax)/100)) + ((parseFloat(this.state.meal_total)) * (parseFloat(this.state.tip)/100));
        return (
            <div className='details'>
                <div className='order-total'>
                    <form>
                        <label htmlFor='meal'>Meal subtotal: ($)</label><br></br>
                        <input name='meal' placeholder={this.state.meal_total} onChange={this.handleMealChange}></input><br></br>
                        <label htmlFor='meal'>Shared items: ($)</label><br></br>
                        <input name='meal' placeholder={this.state.shared_items} onChange={this.handleSharedItemsChange}></input><br></br>
                        <label htmlFor='tax'>Tax: (%)</label><br></br>
                        <input name='tax' placeholder={this.state.tax} onChange={this.handleTaxChange}></input><br></br>
                        <label htmlFor='tip'>Tip: (%)</label><br></br>
                        <input name='tip' placeholder={this.state.tip} onChange={this.handleTipChange}></input><br></br>
                        <label htmlFor='total'>Grand Total: ($)</label><br></br>
                        <input name='total' value={grand_total.toFixed(2)} readOnly></input><br></br>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <PersonList persons={this.state.persons} />
                {this.renderAddPerson()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Person extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            person_tax: props.person_tax,
            person_tip: props.person_tip,
            person_meal_subtotal: 0,
            shared_items: props.shared_items,
        }
    }

    handlePersonSubtotal = event => {
        this.setState({
            person_meal_subtotal: event.target.value
        });
    };

    render() {
        let person_total = parseFloat(this.state.person_meal_subtotal) + parseFloat(this.props.shared_items) + ((parseFloat(this.state.person_meal_subtotal)) * (parseFloat(this.state.person_tax)/100)) + ((parseFloat(this.state.person_meal_subtotal)) * (parseFloat(this.state.person_tip)/100));
        let shared_items = this.state.shared_items / this.props.counter;
        return (
            <div className='person'>
                <div className='total-details'>
                    <h3>Person {this.props.counter} </h3>
                    <form>
                        <label htmlFor='person-meal'>Personal Subtotal: $ </label>
                        <input name='person-meal' value={this.state.person_meal_subtotal} onChange={this.handlePersonSubtotal}></input>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className='breakdown'>
                    <h3>Should Pay</h3>
                    <div className='person-details'>
                        <p>Shared: ${(parseFloat(shared_items)).toFixed(2)}</p><br></br>
                        <p>Tax: ${((parseFloat(this.state.person_tax)/100) * parseFloat(this.state.person_meal_subtotal)).toFixed(2)}</p><br></br>
                        <p>Tip: ${((parseFloat(this.state.person_tip)/100) * parseFloat(this.state.person_meal_subtotal)).toFixed(2)}</p><br></br>
                        <p>Total: ${person_total.toFixed(2)}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        )
    }
}




class Calculator extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Details/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion would be if the form is not filled do not allow the user to add persons.

Based on the analysis of the above code, you are not linking state with number of persons array of object and not updating the values. only global data on state is getting updated on each change.

```
this.state = {
    meal_total: 0, /*updated*/
    shared_items: 0, /*updated*/
    tax: 0, /*updated*/
    tip: 0, /*updated*/
    persons: [], /*not updated on each action update, its only getting re-render or getting the state during new person add action*/
    counter: 1, /*updated*/
};
```

You need to update the state.persons: [] each actions to the unique persons array

```
handleTaxChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            tax: event.target.value,
            persons: <-- update the number of persons selected array with tax  -->
        });
    };
```

Code that calls the render person list which seems having old values each time rendering->

```
<PersonList persons={this.state.persons} />
```

You need to access and update the tax for individual person.

Happy Coding!